# Finding Probabilities of Distribution Functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I recently turned in an assignment and had an error on it, or so I'm told, I'm not entirely convinced just yet. The problem was as follows:

$$F(x) =\begin{cases}1-\frac{16}{x^2},  & x\ge4 \\ 0, & x<4 \end{cases}$$

There were a number of different things I was to do with this problem. It wasn't until we were finding a few simple probabilities that the confusion set in.

It is my understanding that given $F$ is a distribution function of a random variable $X$, for an event concerning $X$, the probability of the event in terms of $F$ is as follows:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\text {Event}& \text{Probability} \\
\hline
X \le a &F(a) \\
X \gt a &1-F(a) \\
X \lt a &F(a-)\\
X \ge a &1-F(a-)\\
X=a &F(a)-F(a-)\\
a\lt X\le b&F(b)-F(a)\\
a\lt X < b&F(b-)-F(a)\\
a\le X \le b&F(b)-F(a-)\\
a\le X < b&F(b-)-F(a-)
\end{array}
$$

where $F(a-)$ and $F(b-)$ represent the left hand limits. (From pg $146$ of Fundamentals of Probability with Stochastic Processes by Saeed Ghahramani)

I was asked to find $P(X \ge 6)$. What I did:

$$P(X \ge 6)=1-F(6-)=1-\frac{16}{36}=\frac{20}{36}=\frac59$$

What my professor had in his solutions (and also another student I spoke with agreed was correct) was:

$$P(X \ge 6)=1-P(X=6)$$
$$P(X=6)=1-\frac{16}{36}=\frac59$$

Thus,
$$P(X \ge 6)=1-\frac59=\frac49$$

What am I missing here? Am I misunderstanding the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $F(x)$ that you have described is clearly a cumulative distribution function. We have $\Pr(X\ge 6)=\Pr(X\gt 6)=1-F(6)=1-\left(1-\frac{16}{36}\right)=\frac{4}{9}$.

Our cdf is *continuous*. Thus there is no need to worry about the distinction between $\ge$ and $\gt$: For any $a$, the probability that the random variable is exactly equal to $a$ is $0$.

**Remark:** Note that $F(x)=\Pr(X\le x)$, and that $F(x)=1-\frac{16}{x^2}$ (for suitable $x$). The mitake in your calculation is a small slip. What you call $F(6-)$ should be $1-\frac{16}{36}$, not $\frac{16}{36}$.

By the way, although $F(6)$ is indeed $\frac{5}{9}$, it is *not true* that $\Pr(X=6)=\frac{5}{9}$. We have $\Pr(X\le 6)=\frac{5}{9}$, but $\Pr(X=6)=0$.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it.

Comment: You are welcome.